# remove initial value " " of a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs, textarea

I would like to remove the initial space in a textarea. When there is no text given to a textarea and you get the textarea.value, you get a single space " " instead of the empty string like a normal input textbox.
Also when there is text (i.e. test) it returns " test". Is it possible to prevent this extra space?
I would prefer to work with the prototype of Textarea because I am using a general procedure to get the values of both input textboxes and textarea's.

For the moment I wrote something like this:

```
Textarea.prototype.value = function() {
        var val = this.value;
        if (val[0] == "0") val.splice(0,1);
        return val;
    };
```

But it doesn't solve the problem, I still get the extra space.

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Comment: To tell the same thing as Sergio in other words: that space exists because your markup put it there.

Comment: It's most likely because you have the opening and closing `<textarea>` tags on different lines in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your HTML should be like this:

```
<textarea></textarea>
---------^ no space, tab or new line there
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply make sure that there is no space between opening and closing tags eg follwing are wrong:

```
<textarea> </textarea>
```

Or

```
<textarea> 
         </textarea>
```

Correct:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

" \b" would result in "". So you could concatinate the string with \b to eliminate the last character of a string